# sklearn regressor: ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do a simple regression using sklearn, but i dont understand how to manually make my own data

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

Y = np.array([22000, 13400, 47600, 7400, 12000, 32000, 28000, 31000, 69000, 48600])
X = np.array([0.62, 0.24, 0.89, 0.11, 0.18, 0.75, 0.54, 0.61, 0.92, 0.88])

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X, Y)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `DeprecationWarning:` says:

> Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise
>   ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if
>   your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a
>   single sample.

So try this:

```
In [70]: regr.fit(X[:, None], Y)
Out[70]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
```

or

```
In [71]: regr.fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), Y)
Out[71]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
```